# grunt init:node not working

Tags: node.js, windows-7, gruntjs

I'm trying to do an intro grunt tutorial.  I've installed git, node.js, and grunt globally (or at least I thought I did using: npm install -g grunt (which installs). I then made a quick directory and entered it (mkdir demo, cd demo), but when I type:

```
> grunt init:node
```

at the prompt I get the following:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v0.1.11)
Fatal error: unable to find local grunt
If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or hasn't been installed locally to your project.  For more information about installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:
```

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Which I've looked at and it says to do what I'm doing and what the tutorial mentions???  Any ideas what I've done wrong?  Node.js and Git have been working fine so I can only assume it is grunt or the install that has failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with grunt you need two elements. a global grunt-cli as you have installed using `npm install -g grunt-cli` and also a local (to the project) copy of grunt itself. so in the folder of your project install this with `npm install grunt --saveDev` this will install a local grunt and also add it to your devDependencies in your package.json file.  you will also need a Gruntfile.js in the project folder.  This is a great write-up http://www.integralist.co.uk/Grunt-Boilerplate.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll read through the url you provide a bit more.  I think one thing I didn't mention was I'm using Windows 7, if that matters since this website indicates I'm on my own for a couple sections based on that.  I don't know if that changes anything.  Using the above it now only says a valid Gruntfile could not be found after I used: npm install grunt --saveDev

Comment: do you have a Gruntfile.js in the project directory? this is required to actually tell grunt what to do. I've used grunt on windows 7 so shouldnt case any problems.

Comment: sorry, I thought it had been generated with the above.  I've found the AppData folder and extracted Gruntfile.js manually and placed it the project.  Now grunt init:node produces Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found is it installed?  As well as Warning: task "init:node" not found. Use --force to continue

Comment: have you npm installed grunt-contrib-jshint?

Comment: i would start with a clean directory and then start a grunt tutorial a fresh to get an idea of how to use it. then use it on an existing project

Comment: wow, this tutorial wasn't very descriptive at all it never mentioned all of this.  no I haven't npm installed grunt-contrib-jshint.  Do I do it globally (-g) as well, same as I did for installing the other packages?  so npm install -g grunt-contrib-jshint

Comment: locally. go read this tutorial and start afresh - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meeting-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript/

Comment: thanks that much easier to read and understand the steps involved,  from the first glance